# GWT - how to build a tree that dynamiclly bring the sons from the server?

Tags: java, gwt, tree

I'm new to GWT , and I want to create a tree that every time that a node is opened (the user clicked on "+" next to the node) , the actions calls a service with the node id , and the returned results is the list of sons.

Which Class do I need to extend in order to change the behaviour of the "expand" action?

Also , can this be done via smartgwt? How?

Thanks

Comment: The problem will be filtering out the daughters.

Comment: May be you could detail little more what your problem is. Is the issue getting GWT rpc working? Or you want to know how to call specific action when tree node is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the "dynamiac tree" in http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwTree (click on "source code" to see the source of the sample.

You might also be interested in http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTree
`CellTree`s are a bit more complex (and thus harder to grasp) but they perform much better than `Tree`s.